# NextJS Redirect not work if user come from browser url bar

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Already three days struggling to solve this problem so any help appreciated.

I have a simple component for check `token` from `localStorage`:

```
import Router from 'next/router';

const Blog = _ => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  useEffect(_ => {
    if(!token){
      Router.push('/')
    }
  }, [])
}
```

This will work if we have a code like this:

```
<Link href="/blog">Blog</Link>
```

Then when you click `blog` you will be redirect to "`/`".
But if you type in browser url bar `/blog` and push enter you will not redirect to main page "`/`".

**UPD:There is no token in localStorage**

Comment: Is this serverless or do you use nodejs as a backend? what web server do you use?

Comment: @DarrylRN At this moment serverless.But I plan to use nodejs.

Comment: what is token variable?

Comment: @Nico Sry for that.I update my question.

Comment: are you able to reproduce it on a sandbox or repo?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no sandboxes available for work with next.Wait a bit I create a repo and add to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. There is no return statement in the functional component. React throws an error if there is nothing returned.
2. If you type '/blog' in the browser, Nextjs throws an error, as the code is first run on the server( the server doesn't have a local storage - Error: localStorage is not defined). To resolve this you can do one of two things -

   - check whether the code is executing on the server or the client and then handle accordingly
   - move localStorage.getItem inside componentDidMount( or hooks equivalent).

```js
import Router from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Blog = _ => {
  useEffect(_ => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (!token) {
      Router.push("/");
    }
  }, []);
  return <p>This is a blog</p>;
};

export default Blog;
```

Comment: Code which I provided this is just for example that's why I dont wrote return statement. -_- .And second I wrote this in both ways in `componentDidMount` and in `useEffect` but this wont help.